# Protect a page to be available only for people who purchases a specific product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I'm trying to protect my page to be available only to users who purchases a specific product.

Here is my code:

```php
function protact_Page() {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return 'https://google.com';

// GET USER ORDERS (COMPLETED + PROCESSING)
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
) );

// LOOP THROUGH ORDERS AND GET PRODUCT IDS
if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
$product_ids = array();
foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $product_ids[] = $product_id;
    }
}
$product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );

if ( !in_array('28', $product_ids))
{
 wp_redirect('https://google.com'); // Add redirect URL Here 
 exit;
}
}
add_shortcode( 'protact_Page', 'protactPage' );
```

And I added the short code `[protact_Page]` like this to that page I want to hide, but it's not working.. what am I missing?

https://learndigital-mena.com/hi-there/ this is the page.

---

**UPDATE**

By the comments I currently have

```php
function protactPage() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) wp_redirect('https://learndigital-mena');

    $product_bought = wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->email, $current_user->ID ,27 );        

    if ( ! $product_bought ) {
        wp_redirect('https://learndigital-mena');   
    }  
} 
add_shortcode( 'protact_Page', 'protactPage' );
```

Comment: View [Redirect function inside a Shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/redirect-function-inside-a-shortcode), also know that you can just use [wc_customer_bought_product()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_customer_bought_product/) versus loop trough orders.

Comment: Your code also contains some mistakes. **1)** Your callback function contains the first value of your shortcode. **2)** `return 'https://goo...'`. will return a string, not redirect to that url (which is your intention)

Comment: this is the best I came through with, I read the article about the redirecting but I couldn't really understand the idea.. Maybe I'm thinking wrong.. but all I want is to hide a page from user who didn't bought the product by redirecting them to an other page, I thought this is the easiest way, but I think I can hide the content and show to them something like "sorry this page available for users who bought the item" would it be possible?

Comment: DId you check if the redirect works inside of the shortcode without the if ? So you will find out if it is the if which is not becoming true, or the redirect function not working. Important notice: only use wp_redirect if you want to redirect to a website which is not your wordpress website. If you just want to redirect to another page of your website, better use wp_safe_redirect for security reasons:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/ Moreover a redirect should come with an exit: `wp_safe_redirect( $url );exit;`

Comment: @rank Thanks for your reply, I've solved the problem.. The If statement wasn't work probably so it was redirecting every time I click anything.